# Any solution for making full screen image slider with responsive design

Tags: wordpress, slider, web-testing, elementor, vs-web-site-project

I'm making a website for a photographer and he want full screen image slider with responsive ssettings . I'm using wordpress + elementor for  it . I am trying a lot but its not working propely in all devices . In some devices it looks smaller and in some devices it cuts of the images. And Its lokks are look perfect in my screen. Please send me option to solve it if you guys have..

website : [weekendshutterbugs.site](http://weekendshutterbugs.site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set  background as cover like:

`background-size: cover;`